# Conflict in use of "selected" attribute in multiselect dropdown using bootstrap-multiselect and conflict with angularjs "selected" directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat, bootstrap-multiselect

I am using [bootstra-multiselect](http://davidstutz.github.io/bootstrap-multiselect/#getting-started) along with angularjs in my project. During testing what i found is, the "selected" attribute name is getting conflict between these two. Following is my HTML markup for my multi select directive.

```
<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple"  name="multiselect[]" data-dropdownmultiselect>    
    <option data-ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{getOptionId(option)}}" data-ng-attr-selected="{{isOptionSelected(option)}}" data-ng-bind-template="{{option.name}}"></option> 
</select>
```

What i found is, `data-ng-attr-selected="{{isOptionSelected(option)}}"` is not getting compiled by angularjs. Seems like angular js "ng-selected" directive is getting applied instead of my required normal attribute.

How can solve this? I don't want to change the code or either bootstra-multiselect or angularjs to avoid future maintability. Is there something in Angularjs to stop running its predefined "ng-selected" directive?

Following is plunker code to demo this problem
[Angularjs and conflict of directive name with other module](http://plnkr.co/edit/bwvJ7LptPWWXzELX923N?p=preview)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `ng-selected="expression"` which will add `selected` attribute with `selected` value in the current `select` option, I don't understand why you are doing it using `ng-attr` while you can control that using `ng-selected="isOptionSelected(option)"`

**Markup**

```
<select id="example-getting-started" multiple="multiple"  name="multiselect[]" data-dropdownmultiselect>    
    <option data-ng-repeat="option in options" value="{{getOptionId(option)}}" 
    ng-selected="isOptionSelected(option)" 
    data-ng-bind-template="{{option.name}}"></option> 
</select>
```

[**Working Plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/VDZDCAWor6ZNWFGfbl1k?p=preview)

Let me know if you want anything else on it, Thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for your solution. Good thing it works in plunker, however when I tried to move same code in my code base then I do see expression is getting executed, however attribute name is still "data-ng-selected" as below, not sure why? <option data-ng-repeat="option in options" value="eq000001" data-ng-selected="selected" data-ng-bind-template="ab crunch machine --updated" class="ng-scope ng-binding">ab crunch machine --updated</option>

Comment: does the angular version of plunkr and your code is same? and i don't think it would affect anyhow by `data-ng-selected="selected"`...i would always add `selected="selected"` when ng-selected expression is true

Comment: I am using angular v 1.3.0. I realized that with my version, i need to return true/false.